# Finding max of the expression $a(t)b(t)+c(t)d(t)$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have no idea how to find the maximum of the following expression,

$a(t)b(t)+c(t)d(t)$

where the functions $b$ and $d$ satisfy  $b(t)^2+d(t)^2=1$

Anyone have a clue?

$t$ is in some compact intervall and the functions $a,c$ are never zero and differentiable on it.

Comment: What does the domain look like?

Comment: What are $a$ and $c$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri fixed

Comment: @TheSimpliFire fixed

Comment: The problem is still to broad - any function from a compact interval to $\mathbb R$ can be written in the form $a(t)b(t)+c(t)d(t)$, simply by setting $a=f, b=1,d=c=0$.

Comment: You don't actually know whether or not they are differentiable, right? Are you looking for numerical methods? Under such general circumnstances we can usually only say that a maximum *exists*.

Comment: @5xum they actually have to be nonzero

Comment: @Fimpellizieri they are differentiable

Comment: If they are differentiable then you can employ usual single-variable calculus methods: the maximum will be either one of the endpoints of the interval or a point where the derivative vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $b(t)^2 + d(t)^2 = 1$, you can always find a substution such that $b(t) = \cos(\theta)$ and $d(t) = \sin(\theta)$ with $\theta(t) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{d(t)}{b(t)} \right) $

This gives the following result

$$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} (a(t) b(t)+c(t) d(t)) = b(t) ( a'(t)+c(t) \dot{\theta}) + d(t) ( c'(t)-a(t) \dot{\theta}) = 0 $$

Which is solved when

$$ \dot{\theta} = \frac{ a'(t) b(t)+c'(t) d(t)}{a(t) d(t)-c(t) b(t)} $$

From there without further knowledge of the functions, we cannot proceed.